# Problema ao utilizar Switch Case no Python 3

Tags: python, algoritmo, python-3.x

```
print ("ESCOLHA A CERVEJA PELO NUMERO")
print ("1-ANTARTICA R$6.00;2-SKOL R$6.50;3-BRAHMA R$8.20;4-SOL R$8.25;")
cerveja = input ("5-NORTENHA R$16.80;6-PROIBIDA R$4.80;7-DEVASSA R$5.90;8-HEINEKEN R$9.00")

q = float(input("Quantas ???"))

def case_1():
    valor_cerveja = 6 * q
    nome = "Antartida"
def case_2():
    valor_cerveja = 6.5 * q
    nome = "Skol"
def case_3():
    valor_cerveja = 8.2 * q
    nome = "Brahma"
def case_4():
    valor_cerveja = 8.25 * q
    nome = "Sol"
def case_5():
    valor_cerveja = 16.8 * q
    nome = "Nortenha"
def case_6():
    valor_cerveja = 4.8 * q
    nome = "Proibida"
def case_7():
    valor_cerveja = 5.9 * q
    nome = "Devassa"
def case_8():
    valor_cerveja = 9 * q
    nome = "Heineken"
def case_default():
    print "Valor invalido"

print (nome,"custa",valor_cerveja,"Reais, por",q,"cerveja(s)")
```

Ele informa que a variável `nome`não foi definida, porém ela foi atribuída.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:/Users/eu/Desktop/algoritmo/cerveja-bar.py", line 34, in <module>
       print (nome,"custa",valor_cerveja,"por",q,"cerveja(s)")
    NameError: name 'nome' is not defined 
>>>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Atualização 2020**:
Está sendo considerada para inclusão no Python 3.10 (~outubro de 2021) a funcionalidade de "pattern matching" com os comandos `match` e `case`. O propósito principal permitir "desestruturar" dados: isso é, a partir de dados de entrada que podem estar de diferentes formas, em JSON, Dicionários, objetos, etc... filtrar e normalizar essas entradas para uso direto no código abaixo do bloco. *Mas* de quebra, esses comandos poderão ser usados também exatamente como o par `switch/case` de linguagens derivadas da sintaxe do `C`. A justificativa para inclusão dos comandos e resumo da funcionalidade estão na [PEP 635](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0635/), com as PEP 634 e PEP 636 como auxiliares. A especificação exata, e mesmo a decisão final para inclusão desses comandos ainda vai ser tomada (depois de Dezembro de 2020). O restante da resposta permanece válido, e permanecerá mesmo depois que esses comandos já estiverem na linguagem - **TL;DR:** use `if/elif` para substituir o `switch/case` do C.

**resposta original**:

Python não tem uma construção como `switch/case` -
em vez disso, a forma preferida e mais simples de se substituir esse comando, que existe nas linguagens que derivaram a sintaxe de C, tais como Java, Javascript, C++, C#, entre outras é usar o `if` do Python, que além do `else` tem também a expressão `elif`.  A palavra chave `def` que você usa aí é a forma de declarar funções e métodos em Python - cuja principal característica é justamente isolar as variáveis internas do ambiente do qual foram chamadas.

Depois de mostrar a forma mais simples (e recomendada), vou comentar o que está acontecendo no seu código:

```
print ("ESCOLHA A CERVEJA PELO NUMERO")
print ("1-ANTARTICA R$6.00;2-SKOL R$6.50;3-BRAHMA R$8.20;4-SOL R$8.25;")
cerveja = raw_input ("5-NORTENHA R$16.80;6-PROIBIDA R$4.80;7-DEVASSA R$5.90;8-HEINEKEN R$9.00")

q = float(raw_input("Quantas ???"))

if cerveja=="1":
    valor_cerveja = 6 * q
    nome = "Antartida"
elif cerveja=="2":
    valor_cerveja = 6.5 * q
    nome = "Skol"
elif cerveja == "3":
    ...
else:
    nome = None
    print "Valor invalido"
if nome:
    print (nome,"custa",valor_cerveja,"Reais, por",q,"cerveja(s)")
```

(eu coloquei o código para Python 2.x - se estiver usando Python 3.x,
troque o "raw_input" de volta para input)

Então, em Python se usa o "if" com "elif" para a construção equivalente a switch/case: O "elif" é uma contração de "else if"  - que é usado em situações semelhantes, quando o swicth case não serve em outras linguagens - por conta da natureza do Python que define qual código está dentro de qual bloco por identação, foi necessária a criação dessa palavra chave a mais.

Uma vantagem do "elif" sobre o "case" é que você pode colocar qualquer condição nele - enquanto que o "case" só permite comparações com constantes. (Também não é preciso um comando "break").

Agora o que aconteceu no seu código:
você provavelmente olhou alguma receita na internet de como fazer um `switch/case` em Python, mas copiou a receita incompleta - você escreveu várias funções que seriam o corpo de cada `case` de forma independente acima - o que pode ser feito - assim como pode ser feito em C, Java. etc... - mas não colocou nenhum comando para que qualquer dessas funções fosse de fato chamada.

Se quiser passar o link da receita original onde você olhou, posso fazer um comentário mais específico - mas desconfio que depois de declarar as várias funções do corpo do código a receita original definia um dicionário, em que as constantes de comparação do "case" seriam as chaves, e as funções seriam colocadas como valores - para o seu código ficaria algo do tipo:

```
escolhas = {"1": case_1, "2": case_2, "3": case_3, "4": case_4 ...} 
escolhas.get(cerveja, default) (q)
```

Perceba que fica bem complicadinho e o "if/elif" são preferíveis. A montagem com o dicionário primeiro recupera um objeto do dicionário, com base na sua variável do "switch"  -por exemplo `escolhas["1"]`  -
esse objeto é uma função,e  você pode chama-la  - por isso a chamada seria `escolhas[ cerveja] (q)` - o par extra de parenteses indica a chamada à função em si. Nesse exemplo, em vez de recuperar a função do dicionário com os colchetes ("[" e "]")  usei o método "get" porque  dessa forma é possível especificar um valor padrão caso a chave não exista (o que você quer fazer no "default" ).

Um outro detalhe é que apesar das funções, nessa forma, poderem "enxergar" o conteúdo de `q` como uma variável global, é altamente recomendado que ela seja passada como um parâmetro.

Agora, além da sua construção, por não ter essa parte do código, não chamar nenhuma das funções, há um problema no seu código com as funções em si: ao usar o `def` você define as duas variáveis cada uma em uma função isolada, e nunca retorna o valor das mesmas - a função  `case_1` por exemplo, seria chamada, faria a atribuição das variáveis, descartaria esses valores e a execução continuaria, com as variáveis indefinidas no ponto onde você chamou a função. Para contornar isso, você teria que retornar valores da suas funções:

```
def case_1(q):
    valor_cerveja = 6 * q
    nome = "Antartida"
    return valor_cerveja, nome
# ou simplesmente:
def case_2(q):
    return  6.5 * q, "Skol"

escolhas = {...}

nome, valor_cerveja = escolhas.get(cerveja, default)(q)
```

(Veja mais sobre retornar múltiplos valores de uma função [aqui](https://pythonhelp.wordpress.com/2011/11/25/retorno-de-multiplos-valores-em-funcoes-com-tuplas/))

E por fim, mas não menos importante - para o que você quer nesse programa, sequer é necessário o uso de "if/elif" (ou seja código diferente a ser executado para cada valor, como no "switch/case"):
o código que você quer executar é sempre o mesmo, só muda o valor da cerveja - isso permite que você usar um dicionário de Python com os dados desejados - e mais ainda, os dados desse dicionário podem ser usados até para imprimir o seu menu - usamos a [formatação de strings](http://python.pro.br/material/cartao-format.pdf) do Python para incluir os dados de cada cerveja numa linha impressa -

```
dados = {
   1: ("Antártica", 6),
   2: ("Skol", 8.5),
   3:  ("Brahma", 8.20),
   ...
}
print "Escolha a cerveja: "
for opcao in sorted(dados):
    print ("{} - {} (R$ {:.02f})".format(opcao, dados[opcao][0], dados[opcao][1]))

cerveja = raw_input("Opção: ")
if not cerveja.isdigit() or not int(cerveja) in dados:
     print("Valor inválido")
else:
   qtd = float(raw_input("Quantidade: "))
   nome = dados[opcao][0]
   valor = dados[opcao][1]
   total = qtd * dados[opcao][1]
   print ("{nome} custa {valor} reais por {qtd} cerveja{plural}".format(
       nome=nome, valor=valor, qtd=qtd, plural=("" if qtd == 1 else "s"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu prefiro usar context managers... Segue uma sugestão de Ian Bell.

```
class Switch:
    def __init__(self, value): 
        self._val = value

    def __enter__(self): 
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback): 
        return False # Allows traceback to occur

    def __call__(self, cond, *mconds): 
        return self._val in (cond,)+mconds

from datetime import datetime

with Switch(datetime.today().weekday()) as case:
    if case(0):
        # Basic usage of switch
        print("I hate mondays so much.")
        # Note there is no break needed here
    elif case(1,2):
        # This switch also supports multiple conditions (in one line)
        print("When is the weekend going to be here?")
    elif case(3,4): 
        print("The weekend is near.")
    else:
        # Default would occur here
        print("Let's go have fun!") # Didn't use case for example purposes
```

Answer (score -2):

Entendo que quer usar o switch case, mas o problema que está retornando é por que as variáveis `nome` e `valor_cerveja` estão dentro de um escopo. Você precisaria definir elas num escopo global (fora da função). Bom, só tentando complementar as respostas acima, pois também estou tentando aprender.